ASP.NET Core 8 - Authorization redirecting to Account/AccessDenied
I have a Razor page with the attribute:
[Authorize(Policy = "Staff")]

and the following authorization configuration:
options.AddPolicy("Staff", policy =>
        {
            policy.RequireAuthenticatedUser();
            policy.AddAuthenticationSchemes("MyAdSchemeName");
            policy.RequireRole("Staff");
        });

When navigating to this page, it correctly redirects me to the login page, however, the return URL passed as the query string param is Account/AccessDenied.
I feel like maybe I'm missing something, but this feels wrong as surely authentication needs to occur before it can be determined whether a 403 should be returned?
My expectation (which may be wrong) is that navigating to the page as a non-authenticated user should redirect to the login page, the login is processed (i.e. roles obtained) & then redirected back to the originally requested page where it can then determine whether they have access (i.e. the required role)?
When I remove the RequireRole call against the policy definition, it works - but obviously allows any all authenticated users regardless of role.
As an aside, Account/AccessDenied doesn't even exist in my app, and I cannot see how to change it. I've tried the following, but to no avail:
services.Configure<CookieAuthenticationOptions>("MyAdSchemeName", options => options.AccessDeniedPath = "/errors/403");

Program.cs code:
var authentication = services.AddAuthentication();

authentication
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(
        configuration.GetSection("AdConfig"), 
        openIdConnectScheme: "MyAdSchemeName", 
        cookieScheme: null, 
        displayName: "MyAdSchemeName");

services.Configure<CookieAuthenticationOptions>("MyAdSchemeName", options => options.AccessDeniedPath = "/errors/403");

services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
{
    options.Events = new CookieAuthenticationEvents
    {
        OnRedirectToAccessDenied = context =>
        {
            context.Response.StatusCode = 403;
            return Task.FromResult(0);
        }
    };
    options.AccessDeniedPath = "/errors/403";
    options.LoginPath = new PathString("/login");
});

services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.FallbackPolicy = options.DefaultPolicy;
    
    
    options.AddPolicy(PolicyNames.Staff, policy =>
    {
        policy.RequireAuthenticatedUser();
        policy.AddAuthenticationSchemes("MyAdSchemeName");
        policy.RequireRole("Staff");
    });
}); 


can you share the program.cs and how you register authentication and authorization?

Actually, there are multiple questions asked here and various factors involved so why don't we take a step back, clean up the configuration a bit and start with a working sample:
services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddCookie();

services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.DefaultPolicy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
        .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
        .Build();

    // staff authentication policy
    options.AddPolicy("Staff", policy =>
    {
        policy.AuthenticationSchemes.Add(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
        policy.RequireClaim(ClaimTypes.Role, "Staff");
    });
});

The above demonstrates configuration of:

the default policy
a custom policy named "Staff", which allows access only to users with "Staff" role

Account/AccessDenied is one of the default redirects of ASP.NET Core Identity and a View with the same name is located under the Views folder, typically. If you want to change that modify the above sample as follows:
services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddCookie(options =>
    {
        options.AccessDeniedPath = "...";
    });

As a extra note, apart from using the Authorize attribute you can apply the "Staff" policy in a whole area, which I find very convenient:
endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "Staff",
    pattern: "{area:exists}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}")
.RequireAuthorization("Staff");

I hope it helps and that you can further adjust it to your customization needs.

The Account/AccessDenied page comes from asp.net core identity part in your project yet you didn't show it. You need to modify the signin configuration so that you can override the redirecting.
builder.Services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = false)
.AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
builder.Services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
{
    options.LoginPath = "/login";
    options.LogoutPath = "/logout";
    options.AccessDeniedPath = "/errors/403";
});

When reach the page with no user logined.

After logining in.

